# How to control error display by JavaScript in Chrome, eg 404 error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, http-status-code-404

I have tried use "try-catch" handle, but it doesn't work. Chrome would still display 404 URL error (I don't want to display it in console);

Sample code you can see below:

```
  try {
    $.post("/APIURL", function(data) {
      $(".hint").fadeIn(300);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no way of preventing HTTP errors being logged by Chrome. In any case, why would you want to?

Comment: Firstly a try/catch is redundant here as the AJAX request is asynchronous. Secondly, you cannot stop the request information being displayed in the console, regardless of what you do.

Comment: @Chris it just not good eye catching; well, thx for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can not disable the chrome console errors, there are multiple ways to catch errors which might get you closer to your goal.

First example, this just enables you to handle POST Failure without try/catch and gives you textStatus so you get some better feedback other than error or success.

```
//catching failure in post
$.post("/APIURL", function(data, textStatus) {
  console.log("post success");
}).fail(function(data,textStatus){
    console.log(textStatus);
});
```

the second will catch any ajax errors on the page in general, this might help to notify users of errors for any ajax requests, not just the one you implemented.

```
//catching ajax failure across the page
$( document ).ajaxError(function( event, request, settings ) {
    $( "#msg" ).append( "<li>Error requesting page " + settings.url + "</li>");
});
```

here's a Jsfiddle to play around with https://jsfiddle.net/c6q6dfxt/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not possible. I think there was a workaround with try catch clauses in older IE versions, but thats not very useful. Anyway, 404 error should not be something to hide, and you should not make it part of your normal workflow - an error is an error. If you need to check the existence of the resource and you don't want to report it to the console, you could make a separate API endpoint that would check if the resource exists and simply return a boolean or something more complex.